# CodeIgniter : How to get data by ID and preview it (Where ID)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have 2 table :

1. product_group
2. product

which is every product have group_id as Foreign Key in the table.

I try to call every product by group_id.

this is my list_group view :

```
 <a href="<?= base_url('list_group/get_product_by_group/'. $value->group_id);?>" class="right-icon"><i class="icon-line-ellipsis"></i></a>
```

I try to attach the group_id in URL.

this is my controller :

```
    public function get_product_by_group($group_id)
    {

            if($this->uri->segment(3))
            {
                    $this->load->database();
                    $group_id = $this->input->get('group_id', TRUE);
                    $data['product_data'] = $this->group_model->list_product_by_group($group_id);
                    $this->load->view('fend/list_product', $data);

            }
            else
            {
                    redirect('list_group');
            }

    }
```

This is my model :

```
        function list_product_by_group($group_id)
        {
                $this->db->select('*');
                $this->db->where('group_id', $group_id);
                $query = $this->db->get('product');
                return $query->result();
        }
```

and the last is list_product view :

```
 <?php
      foreach($product_data as $value)
      {
 ?>

   <div class="masonry-thumbs col-3" data-big="2" data-lightbox="gallery">
      <a href="<?= base_url('uploads/'. $value->product_picture);?>" data-lightbox="gallery-item"><img class="image_fade" src="<?= base_url('uploads/'. $value->product_picture);?>" alt="Gallery Thumb 1"></a>
   </div>

 <?php
     }
 ?>
```

I got no error, but the data did not appear in product_view.

Thanks for your help :))

Comment: print_r($product_data); in your view and check what it return

Comment: have your code enters into model code??

Comment: @saty : sorry I didnt get it

Comment: You don't need this line `$group_id = $this->input->get('group_id', TRUE);` may be you getting wrong value for `$group_id` for this line.

Comment: @saty : print_r() result is null,,, I get array()

Comment: what should I do right now ? thanks

Comment: just remove this line `$group_id = $this->input->get('group_id', TRUE);` it will solve your problem.

Comment: @ShaifulIslam : thanks for your answer, It's solved, but I still didn't understand why I should erase the code..

Comment: Coz you were not getting any value within your `$this->input->get('group_id', TRUE)` instead of it you were passing that value within your controller `public function get_product_by_group($group_id)` which'll overwrite your value within `if` condition and results it into empty value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the line `$group_id = $this->input->get('group_id', TRUE);` it will solve your problem.

**Here is the explanation:**

Your controller function name is `public function get_product_by_group($group_id)` so when you go to this link `localhost/norwin/list_group/get_product_by_group/1` 1  will be passed as $group_id into your `get_product_by_group` function.So your final function will be like this

```
public function get_product_by_group($group_id='')
//write this way so that you can call the url like
//localhost/norwin/list_group/get_product_by_group
{

        if($group_id)//no need to check uri->segment
        {
                $this->load->database();                    
                $data['product_data'] = $this->group_model->list_product_by_group($group_id);
                $this->load->view('fend/list_product', $data);

        }
        else
        {
                redirect('list_group');
        }

}
```

Comment: Don't you think `!empty($group_id)` or `isset()` would be more advisable, if I'm not wrong. So that next time OP'll have an idea of checking a variable in future

Comment: No need to check empty ,Even though it will work here.There is little difference between `if(!empty($group_id) )`and `if($group_id)`. But here `if($group_id)` is perfect.

Comment: I would use `if ( (int)$group_id > 0 )` and also `$query->num_rows() > 0`  in model.

Comment: @NarendraSisodia you can check the difference here http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php. But that is different Question.

Comment: @Tpojka yes checking int is good.But OP did not checked it so its his job he will check or not.

Comment: @Shaiful-Islam Agree with you. It can avoid unnecessary issues in future. My moto is 'offer more'. Especially regarding good work practice.